# Correlation = 1 with three random variables

Tags: probability, correlation, covariance, linearity

Let $A, B, C$ be random variables with covariance $cov(A B) = 0$ and correlation $corr(B, C) = 1$.

Is it true that $cov(A C) = 0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it has to be $0$. Assume $\text{corr}(A,C)=p$. Then, the correlation matrix of the three random variables is
$$C=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&p\\0&1&1\\p&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$

And, this has to be positive semi-definite ([PSD](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125412/is-every-correlation-matrix-positive-semi-definite)). A first condition of positive semi-definiteness is having non-negative determinant. Here, $\det(C)=-p^2$ which means $p$ can only be $0$. That makes also covariance $0$.

Note that, it'd have been tempting to say that $\text{corr}(B,C)=1$ implies a linear relationship between the two RVs and this makes covariance of $A$ and $C$ zero, but, this [may not](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/218198/are-there-ways-in-which-perfect-correlation-i-e-textcovx-y-1-can-st) be the case when the probability space is infinite and the linear relationship does not hold for some $B$ and $C$ values with zero probability measure.

Comment: When a relationship holds except on a set of zero probability, we still say it holds (and will qualify that statement with "almost surely" in order to be clear).  Thus, the argument is valid: because the correlation of $B$ and $C$ is $\pm 1,$ $B$ and $C$ are linearly related a.s.; say, $C=\alpha B + \beta.$ Then $\operatorname{Cov}(A,C)=\alpha\operatorname{Cov}(A,B)$ and the result follows as a special case.